# find period from simple harmonic motion position

Tags: calculus, derivatives, mathematical-physics

> If an object suspended from a spring is displaced vertically
> from its equilibrium position by a small amount and re-
> leased, and if the air resistance and the mass of the spring
> are ignored, then the resulting oscillation of the object is
> called simple harmonic motion. Under appropriate condi-
> tions the displacement y from equilibrium in terms of time
> t is given by $$y=A\cos \omega t$$ where A is the initial displacement at time t = 0, and ω is
> a constant that depends on the mass of the object and the
> stiffness of the spring (see the accompanying ﬁgure). The
> constant |A| is called the amplitude of the motion and ω the
> angular frequency..... **The period T is the time required to make one complete
> oscillation. Show that T = 2π/ω.**

If I take **amplitude** equal to $2\pi$ than, I found an equation which is nearly related to period. But, I noticed there's a $\cos$. I don't know how to remove it. How to solve it? I would request for hint.

Comment: How are you taking the amplitude equal to $2\pi$? Could you please elaborate about it in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time period is defined as the time interval taken for the system to finish one complete oscillation. This means that the phase difference between the initial and final position is $2\pi$. This means that:
$$\omega \Delta t=2\pi$$ so that $$\Delta t=\frac {2\pi}{\omega}$$
Remember that, amplitude is not a property of a system, it depends upon the external forces acting upon the system. Hence you cannot simply define it to be $2\pi$.

Comment: But, what about $\cos$? How we can remove it? Where does it go?

Comment: It doesn't "go" anywhere. Just that the phase changes by $2\pi$, since $\cos (\theta)=\cos(\theta+ 2\pi)$